# How to show/hide search bar with same toolbar button

Tags: ios, xcode, button, show, searchbar

I have a toolbar button

```
UIBarButtonItem *systemItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSearch target:self action:@selector(pressButton2:)];
    systemItem2.style = UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered;
```

and a press action

```
- (void) pressButton2:(id)sender{
        mapSearch.hidden = NO;
}
```

in viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  mapSearch.hidden = YES;
}
```

**How can I show and hide searchbar with same button (second press)?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand you would like to toggle the `mapSearch.hidden`. Here is a solution

```
mapSearch.hidden = !mapSearch.hidden;
```

or

```
mapSearch.hidden = (mapSearch.hidden) ? NO : YES;
```